# Baal Teshuva Smicha Program Recommendations

Tags: yeshiva-school, baal-teshuva, semicha

Looking for a Smicha program in Israel for Baal Teshuva.
Happy with anywhere in Israel. Ideally would be able to cater for a married couple and children.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "for Baal teshuva"? You mean beginners? Experienced learners with similar backgrounds? Specific training for Baalei teshuva (complicated shailos/kiruv related etc.)? Also what do you mean cater for married couple with children. Generous stipend? Living accommodations? In any event Ohr Somayach has a smicha program called Ohr LaGolah which might be what you're looking for. Aish used to have a smicha program but I heard it was shut down.

Comment: @robev did you mean Shu"t? :P